# $\left(1+2\cos\theta\right)\left(1-\cos\theta\right)=1+\cos\theta-2\cos^2\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble trying to show this.  I have reams of paper on the floor and I am tired, I need some help.

I know that $1+\cos\theta-2\cos^2\theta$ equals  $\cos\theta + \sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta$

after that I keep going in circles.

Comment: If you want to show the equality in the title this is not trigonometry, you just have to multiply out.

Comment: Just realized that, $1+x-2x^2$.

Comment: So you realized that this question has nothing to do with $\cos$ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making it harder than it is. Use $$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd,$$ simplify, and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

and $\sin^2\theta = 1-\cos^2\theta$

Answer (score 2):

We know that if in the second order equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$, $a+b+c=0$ then; it can be decomposed to $(x-1)(x-\frac{c}{a})=0$ . Now consider $x$ in your eqaution as $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: I made that realization, see my comment

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Yes. You did it right. In fact by adding the coefficients you get zero.